# How to show image in place of a user input URL in a textarea field?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

Using NodeJS, Express and MongoDB, i have a text area for a user to add text to a blog.

What I want is for the user to be able to put image URL inside the text area and submit his post, and the application will show an image in place of that URL. How can I do that ?

I've tried to simply add a URL into it, but it doesn't work. I've also tried to add strong tags to some text but it doesn't get applied. As I will be the only one user able to post, I would also like to have that functionality.

Here is the HTML part to create a new post :

```
<div class="field">
     <label>Contenu</label>
     <textarea name="body"></textarea>
</div>
```

To show the post (I'm showing only the body part) :

```
<div class="description">
     <p><%=blog.body%></p>
</div>
```

And in case you want to see my CREATE route for the post (which does work) :

```
router.post('/blogs',middleware.isLoggedIn,function(req,res){
        var titre = req.body.title;
        var image = req.body.image;
        var body = req.body.body;
        var author = {
            id : req.user._id,
            username : req.user.username
        }
        var newBlog ={title:titre ,image:image, body:body, author:author};
        Blog.create(newBlog, function(err,newBlog){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                res.render('blog/new');
            }
            else
            {
                console.log(newBlog);
                res.redirect('/blogs');
            }
        });
});
```

What I want is the user input (only me for posts) to be translated to image for URL input or font style when I use tags like 'strong' in a textarea.

Answer (score 0):

You can't display an image directly inside a textarea control.

The closes you can get is overlay an image on it, but it will not be part of the information in the textarea. That is, text will not flow around it and when posting the form it will not be included in the data for the textarea.

Perhaps a writable div (content editable) would suit your purposes better. html

but you can use the contenteditable attribute specifies whether the content of an element is editable or not.

Note: When the contenteditable attribute is not set on an element, the element will inherit it from its parent.

```
<div contentEditable="true"> type here
    <img src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQCze-mfukcuvzKk7Ilj2zQ0CS6PbOkq7ZhRInnNd1Yz3TQzU4e&t=1" />
</div>
```

but read this link: [Why ContentEditable is Terrible](https://medium.engineering/why-contenteditable-is-terrible-122d8a40e480)